# Error while calculating percentage

Tags: c#

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible'.

I am getting this error while converting. I have two text boxes in one I have amount and in another I have percentage value should come in third text box.

```
public partial class caltxt : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   double amt1;
    double exc;
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void txtamt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         amt1 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble (txtamt));

        //decimal PercentageRate = Convert.ToDecimal(this.txtamt.Text);

    }


    protected void txtexc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double exc = Math.Round (Convert.ToDouble(this.txtexc.Text));


        // decimal    temp = (Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(txtexc.Text) / Convert.ToDecimal(txtamt.Text)*100));
       // txttotalexc.Text = temp.ToString();
    }

    protected void txttotalexc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double totat = Math.Round (Convert.ToDouble(exc) /100)* Convert.ToDouble(amt1); //+ Convert.ToInt32(this.txtexc.Text);
        this.txttotalexc.Text = totat.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace or the console log?

Answer (score 2):

you should convert the `Textbox.Text`property to `Double` instead of the `TextBox` itself

replace

```
amt1 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble (txtamt));
```

with

```
amt1 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(txtamt.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems problem with this line

```
   amt1 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(txtamt));
```

In order to make it work you should use this line

```
  amt1 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(txtamt.Text));
```

Reason:txtamt has no value it is simply a object while txtamt.Text has a value

Comment: now the solution is not seen in tne txttotalexc textbox

Comment: change the text of  txttotalexc and see wheter its event trigger?